# Child of constraint with bones and objects

Tags: constraints

Trying to attach a bone to an object outside of the rig but its just not following with the child of constraint. I've clicked set inverse but it still doesn't follow. Can you actually make bones do this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just made another external bone and it tracks no problem. If anyone can tell me if childing to an object and not a bone is possible id love to know where i went wrong

Comment: oh....i spoke too soon. Now the entire first rig follows the external rig when i only want the one bone to follow